# JavaScript removes slash from JSP variable

Tags: javascript, jsp, variables, escaping, slash

Have JSP variable `${remoteFolder}`

It's value is ***\\file-srv\demo***

Use jQuery embedded in this JSP.

jQuery resolves `${remoteFolder}` variable as ***\file-srvdemo*** ,i.e. one slash is removed.

How to remain initial value of this var?

**edited**: when `${remoteFolder}` is used inside `form` tag, that it resolved OK.

**edited2:**

JS part of JSP, slashes are stripped out..

```
  <script>
        var oScript = document.createElement("script");
        oScript.type = "text/javascript";
        oScript.text = "var $j = jQuery.noConflict();";
        oScript.text+= "$j(document).ready(function(){";
        ...
       oScript.text+= "'script':'<%= request.getContextPath()   %>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=${remoteFolder}',";
        ...
        oScript.text+= "});"; 
        document.body.appendChild(oScript);        
    </script>
```

**edited3:**

earlier usage of `${remoteFolder}` var,that was all OK with slashes
    < form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="uploadFrame" action="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=${remoteFolder}">

Comment: Odd, SO stripped one `\\` out.

Comment: yes, '\' is stripped out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems here.

First, the `\` is an escape character in JS strings. When you want to represent a `\` in a JS string, you need to double-escape it: `\\`. Easiest way would be using [JSTL](http://download.java.net/maven/1/jstl/jars/jstl-1.2.jar) [`fn:replace`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) for this.

```
var jsVariable = "${fn:replace(javaVariable, '\\', '\\\\')}";
```

Second, you want send it as an URL parameter. The `\` is an illegal character in URL parameter. You need to URL-encode it. Easiest way would be using Javascript's `escape()` function for this.

```
var urlParameter = escape(jsVariable);
```

Summarized, the

```
oScript.text+= "'script':'<%= request.getContextPath()   %>/uploadFile?portletId=${portletId}&remoteFolder=${remoteFolder}',";
```

needs to be replaced by

```
oScript.text += "'script':"
    + "'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/uploadFile"
    + "?portletId=${portletId}"
    + "&remoteFolder=" + escape("${fn:replace(remoteFolder, '\\', '\\\\')}")
    + "',";
```

Alternatively, you can just use `/` instead of `\` as file path separator. This works perfectly in Windows as well. You don't need to escape them for use in strings, you however still need to URL-encode it.

```
oScript.text += "'script':"
    + "'${pageContext.request.contextPath}/uploadFile"
    + "?portletId=${portletId}"
    + "&remoteFolder=" + escape("${remoteFolder}")
    + "',";
```

Comment: The problem is that just replacing the backslash isn't necessarily enough. What if there's a double-quote character in the string? Or two-byte Unicode characters? Well in this case it's a file name, so maybe it's safe to make an assumption or two.

Comment: BalusC, thank you for clarification. I will try this way.Initially i tried escaping, but /\f gave me symbol looked like square,when i check this string in notepad.

Answer (score 2):

That's JavaScript rather than jQuery. You'll need to escape any backslash you want to be preserved when creating JavaScript string literals using an extra backslash.

Comment: inside form tag inside action attribute this variable contains all slashes OK, strange..

Comment: Could you post the relevant JavaScript that your JSP is generating?

Comment: see "edited2" section ,please, there is a chunk of code ,where slashes unexpectedly stripped - it's jQuery part of "uploadify" plugin

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I meant the relevant snippet of the HTML source of the page as served to the browser, not the JSP.

Comment: if you mean servlet part,that UI is encapsulated in JSP only,our Servlet and Portlets do logic work only.Is that you mean? thank you.

Comment: i mentioned that HTML contained in JSP only

Comment: perhaps, to use Javascript base64?

Comment: You could use base 64, but you'd need to write/find a decoding function for that (not every browser has a built-in base 64 decoding function). Escaping every backslash in your Java string with an extra backslash is all you need. What I was trying to ask was what you see if you use "view source" in your browser, so that we could be sure that it is the backslash escaping problem.

Comment: i see \file-srvdemo  instead of \\file-srv\demo

Answer (score 2):

I find that I cannot write a serious web application without having my own EL function library with some critical functions in it. Among those is a "jsQuote" (or "escapeJS", depending on what sort of mood I'm in) function, whose intent is to "protect" expanded strings so that they can be dropped into Javascript string constants. It's analogous to `fn:escapeXml()` but instead of targetting the HTML syntax it targets Javascript. Generally what it has to do is check for backslash, the quote characters, newline & the other common control characters, and then any characters outside the 7-bit printable range. With such a function, you can always safely do something like this:

```
<script>
  // ...
  var s = 'A string ${yourLib:escapeJS(some.java.bean.property)} constant';
  // ...
</script>
```

I really wish such a thing would become part of the JSTL standard, but I'm not hopeful. Luckily it's really easy to write.

Comment: good idea actually, taking into consideration,that such cases oftenly occurred for web developers

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `$remotefolder` to **\\\\file-srv\\demo** since javascripts interprets \ as escape char, thereby needing \\ to print \.

Comment: it came from backend and in form tah it's resolved ok..,but in jQuery ready function it strripped the slash